# Undefined variable error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a trouble about views in laravel
.here is Controller

```
public function transactions()
    {
        $transactions = Transaction::all();

        return view('admin.transaction', compact('transactions'));
    }
```

here is view

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$transaction->bank_number}}</td>
        <td>{{$transaction->transaction_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$transaction->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{$transaction->description}}</td>
        <td>{{$transaction->made_on}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

and error is

> Undefined variable: transactions in view.

Please help me! thanks

Comment: What happens when you've tried this: `return view('admin.transaction')->with($transactions, compact('transactions'));`

Comment: Could you `dd($transaction)` and post the output in your question please, thus be sure that you created an admin folder with a `transaction.blade.php`

Answer (score 1):

Use like below

```
   return view('admin.transaction')->with('transactions', $transactions);
```